# Importing Flask-SocketIO instance

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to integrate Flask-SocketIO into my application and having bad time. I don't understand how to pass SocketIO instance within the same context. Sorry i can't provide you with the exact code or error logs atm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions regarding this ticket, feel free to ask.

run.py (<-- Application starts from here)

```
from app import app, socketio
socketio.run(app)
```

app/__init__.py

```
import json, stomp
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from app.dalet.DAPIDB import Handler
from flask.ext.bower import Bower
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
Bower(app)
with open('env.json') as data_file:
    app.config['locale'] = json.load(data_file)['locale']
app.config.from_object("config."+app.config['locale'])
API = Handler(app.config)

from app.dalet.LotusOrb import LotusOrb
conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', LotusOrb(API))
conn.start()
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
conn.subscribe('Mortred', 0)
```

app/dalet/LotusOrb.py

```
import stomp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from app import socketio

class LotusOrb(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, API):
        self.API = API
    def on_error(self, headers, rawmessage):
        print('received an error "%s"' % rawmessage)
    def on_message(self, headers, rawmessage):
        socketio.emit('current_title', self.API.getduration(itemidmb))
```

Obviously enough, i just need to execute socketio.emit. Application boots up, but client-side JS doesn't show up any message. (I'm 100% sure in client JS, it works if i write code in app/**init**.py) There is no error in output whatsoever, the mistake is probably in instances of socketio variable.

What's wrong with my importing?

EDIT: I've updated code.

Comment: Whenever you report an error, please add the complete stack trace to help people understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you'll need to monkey patch the std libs according to whichever framework you're using to run your server:

```
# probably
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
# or possibly
import eventlet; eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

I had [a similar issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/203).